# JQuery Modal window prevents .Net events from firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using a Jquery modal window with an asp button inside. The problem here is that jQuery-UI creates the dialog outside of the  element, so clicking on it never submits the form. I have tried to fix this by adding:

```
$(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

However, I am new to Jquery and not sure where to add this line. I thought I was close any help? Thanks!

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var dlg = $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });
        });
    },

    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); // <--APPENDING HERE
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $(document).height() - 25
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        300,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 200);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            300,
            function () {
                self.close();
            }
        );
    }
};

OSX.init();

});
```

Comment: Why do you want it inside your form? To submit the values, I presume?

Comment: From my research the events will not fire unless the div is inside the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(el).modal({appendTo: 'form'}); fixed the problem
see below for exact usage.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close,
                appendTo: 'form' // <--This appends to the form
            });
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems like, do not use `.dialog()`

You can use the following styles to create the effect of a dialog

```
#mydialog{

    z-index:1000;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;

}

#overlay{

   z-index:999;
   background:transparent url(bg.png) repeat ...; 
}
```

Note you could even use [`$.blockUI()`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) for the overlay effect.

```
$('#mydialog').draggable(); //.resizable() if you want to
```